# PDO and Database Class - Getting Table Schema

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got this class "Database", it extends PDO, and I can do searches and find all perfect like this:

```
public function select($sql, $array = array(), $fetchMode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC){
    $sth = $this->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $sth->bindValue("$key", $value);
    }

    $sth->execute();
    return $sth->fetchAll($fetchMode);
}
```

But now i want a function that lets me retrieve a tables schema...

I tried to work with PDO:cubic_schema, but can't make it work. I keep getting that either the constant cant be found or the method cannot be found, here's a try...

```
    public function schema($table) {
    $table_information = $this->cubrid_schema(PDO::CUBRID_SCH_CLASS, $table);
    return $table_information;
}
```

any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I've never used that PDO function, but I can only find a doc on `cubrid_schema` not `cubic_schema`...

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$this->cubrid_schema(PDO::CUBRID_SCH_CLASS, $table);`. If you're getting undefined symbol, are you sure you're using a new enough PHP version?

Comment: Also; `PDO_CUBRID is a driver that implements the PHP Data Objects (PDO) interface to enable access from PHP to CUBRID databases.`. Are you sure that's what you're looking for since you tagged MySQL?

Comment: sorry yeah it's cubrid, i miss copied it here lol

Comment: $this->cubrid_schema(PDO::CUBRID_SCH_CLASS, $table);
 === This returns:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::cubrid_schema() in /var/www/mvc/Core/libs/Database.php on line 15 is what's

Comment: Take a look at MySQL's [SHOW CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html) and [EXPLAIN | DESCRIBE | DESC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html).

Comment: Most likely [CUBRID](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.cubrid.php) functions aren't installed on your version of PHP. My opinion is to go with Rolando suggestion above anyways though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay i found my solution, and it was not to use cubric at all....

```
public function schema($table) {

    $q = $this->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$table`");
    $q->execute();
    $table_fields = $q->fetchAll();
}
```

this returns :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Field] => dataid
            [0] => dataid
            [Type] => int(11)
            [1] => int(11)
            [Null] => NO
            [2] => NO
            [Key] => PRI
            [3] => PRI
            [Default] => 
            [4] => 
            [Extra] => auto_increment
            [5] => auto_increment
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Field] => text
            [0] => text
            [Type] => varchar(255)
            [1] => varchar(255)
            [Null] => NO
            [2] => NO
            [Key] => 
            [3] => 
            [Default] => 
            [4] => 
            [Extra] => 
            [5] => 
        )

)
```